# How to refresh the attribute table of a layer after editing the table in the DB-Manager?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, database

Is there any way to refresh the attribute table of a layer after editing the table (e.g. add a column) in the DB-Manager?

Comment: the changeDataSource plugin is the fastest way and works very well with .csv files

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short and sweet:

1. Install [changeDataSource plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/).
2. Right-click on the layer in the Layers Panel and select `Change vector datasource`.
3. In the dialog box that appears, just hit `OK` without changing any of the settings.

Basically, you are "changing" the vector datasource to what it already was, but this forces QGIS to reload the layer definition.

*Tested in QGIS 2.14 on Linux Mint 17.2.*

Comment: I've had to reselect the same datasource in order for that to work.

Comment: 5 years later, this hasnt been automatically implemented in qgis 3 but this answer still works

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your working with a PostGIS database, you can update the statistics of the table of interest by using the `ANALYSE` function:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html

In your case you can execute the statement inside the DB-manager by pressing the button marked in the attached image and executing the `ANALYSE` statement in the window, which is also marked. The query would be `ANALYSE yourschema.yourtable`.The analyse command should update your table, so that when you access the information again it should reflect the changes you have made.
[image: DB manager window]

Comment: This doesn't refresh the attribute table (right click on layer -> Open Attribute Table).

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand well if you mean to refresh the table in QGIS after a change to the columns is made?

As far as I know, only close and open the project or re-adding the table will make this happen. As long as you saved the default style in the database that might be the fastest way.

When a column is added with the Field Calculator the changes are instantly visible but the DB manager offers more control in defining the field type so I understand why that may not be a solution.

Comment: Is there any Python command to refresh the attribute table? I've also noticed that 'Show Feature Count' ignores changes made in the DB-Manager (add features/delete features).

Comment: `layer.dataProvider().forceReload()` should do the trick