# Reloading layer in Layers Panel with Python after modifying it in DB Manager

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, layers

I often have to reload layers in the layers panel after doing changes in the DB-Manager (add a column, delete a default value, ...). At the moment I use the changeDatasource plugin. Can this also be done using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read several answers for this specific question; none of them seems to work. The only effective solution I could find is:

```
layer.setDataSource( layer.source(), layer.name(), layer.providerType() )
```

*Tested in QGIS v2.14.8.*

Answer (score 7):

if you have your layer as a variable, simply `layer.reload()`

You can obtain a list of all layers of the current project from  `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()`

If you don’t care about reloading all other layers at the same time, the one-liner

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().reloadAllLayers()
```

does the job, too.

References:

- https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html
- http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html

Comment: Running `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().reloadAllLayers()` in the Python console returns an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined`

Comment: `layer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
layer.reload()` doesn't work.

Comment: in the Python console `iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer().reload()` should work – checking it here in a moment

Comment: It works as long as a layer is selected in the layer list (`QgsMapCanvas` refers to to the user interface, `QgsMapLayerRegistry` to the QGIS project)

`QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().reloadAllLayers()` works as expected, too.

Comment: Perhaps it's a QGIS 2.x/3.x issue. I'll test this in QGIS 2.18 tomorrow.

Comment: For testing purposes I've added a new column in the DB-Manager. The Python console (QGIS 2.18.3) returns no errors running your statements but nothing happens. The new  column is still not listed in the attribute table. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ah, ok, that’s a restriction of QGIS. It does not refresh the structure of the dataset, but only its content. 
Compare http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190440/how-to-refresh-the-attribute-table-of-a-layer-after-editing-the-table-in-the-db/190798

Comment: try `layer.dataProvider().setDataSourceUri(layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())`

Answer (score 5):

`QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()` worked for me on QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  A good answer should include details about how to use your suggestion and info about what it does.  Please [edit] your answer to add additional info.