# Force layer reload in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm working on integrating QGIS and PostGIS, but looking for a way to force a layer reload. I don't need it to be automated -- I'm happy to run a command every time I want to refresh the map.  The comments on this question:

[How to refresh the attribute table of a layer after editing the table in the DB-Manager?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190440/how-to-refresh-the-attribute-table-of-a-layer-after-editing-the-table-in-the-db)

Suggest that `layer.dataProvider().forceReload();` is one option, but when I open `Plugins > Python Console` and run that I get an error:

```
layer.dataProvider().forceReload();
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'layer' is not defined
```

I thought maybe I needed to use the name of my layer, but that didn't fix it:

```
example.dataProvider().forceReload();
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'example' is not defined
```

Am I misunderstanding that suggestion? Is there another way to accomplish this in the python console?

Comment: did u assign any value to **layer** ? (dumb question ...)

Comment: something like `layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("YOUR_LAYER_NAME")`...

Comment: @snaileater ahhh. ty